# How to query on multiple tables in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have three models. They are like below

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :shop
  has_one :address
end

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user      
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user      
end
```

Address model has state_id column. Now I want to get all shops which shop's owner `address.state_id` is 123456.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Shop.joins(user: :address).where(addresses: { state_id: 123456 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can describe relation of `Shop` and `Address` via `User`. Like this:

```
# models/shop.rb
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :address, through: :user
end
```

Then you can issue a simple call:

```
Shop.includes(:address).where(addresses: { state_id: 123456 })
```